# Facebook Like Button Error - iFrame showing profile picture instead of like button

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have sort of an odd issue. I have never seen this before and can not find anything on the web after about a day of searching.

For one, this is only happening on one of our clients' computers. So we can not recreate it, or test it.

We are using a standard like button at my work on a site we are developing. We added the like button, it is displaying on every browser, save for IE 8 (which is as far back as we are supporting) on Windows 7. And like I said, it's only happening on one client computer, and we don't have access to that computer.

Instead of showing the like button, it is displaying a wide iFrame box with a white background and a red box with the user's profile picture (if they are logged in) and the word "switch" that appears to be a link.

Have any of you seen this before?

[image]

I wish I could give you a link, but I can't for NDA reasons.

Here is the code, pretty basic Like button code...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APPIDHERE";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Annndddd here is the html where the button is placed:

```
<div class="facebook space">
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="@Request.Url" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false"></div>
                    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cause we are at a loss.

Comment: I've seen that behavior before. It looks similar to what what happens when you attempt to display Facebook in a frameset. There must be some sort of user customization script (like AdBlock or Greasemonkey) on the client's machine that is bollixing up the Facebook javascript. Can you get them to install a new browser like Safari or Opera for testing?

Comment: It doesn't happen on Safari, she has tested other browsers. Only in IE (her version is 8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when the user that is accessing the site with the Like button is both logged into Facebook AND currently using Facebook in the context of one of the Pages s/he is an Admin of. All you have to do is have the user go back into Facebook and switch his/her user context back to him/herself rather than the page.

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there any way around things, rather than your solution, you think?

Comment: Not that I ever found, unfortunately. But a lot has changed since the last time I looked at this, so you never know.